# Fragment dialog crashes app, any alternative fix?

Tags: android

trying to remove the top banner layer of an Android app, 
and I made this change in Android Manifest file,

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
```

This crashed the app, and from another question in Stackoverflow itself, I changed

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
```

to

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity
```

And it worked, however, in the same Activity there is also a Dialog present, and whenever the dialog is clicked, it crashes the app again, So looking for a fix! any help will be appreciated.

Here is the logcat:

```
05-16 21:25:27.796    1839-1839/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia, PID: 1839
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.onCreate(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:113)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreate(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:146)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDialog.<init>(AppCompatDialog.java:47)
            at android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.<init>(AlertDialog.java:92)
            at android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog$Builder.create(AlertDialog.java:882)
            at zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia.FireMissiles.onCreateDialog(FireMissiles.java:26)
            at android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment.getLayoutInflater(DialogFragment.java:308)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:955)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1138)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:740)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1501)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:458)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

The code for the dialog Activity :

```
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;

public class FireMissiles extends DialogFragment {
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Use the Builder class for convenient dialog construction
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

    builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_info, null))
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.fire, new  

   DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    // FIRE ZE MISSILES!
                }
            });

    // Create the AlertDialog object and return it
    return builder.create();
   }
}
```

Comment: could you please post the code of your Dialog too..

Comment: I ve added that, This one was referenced from developer.google and altered it for my need

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
```

to

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
```

Comment: That worked buddy, however , there is a problem in dialog now, that is the text area of the whole dialog looks black, any idea what might be causing it ?  :)

Comment: I do not know but looks like an unrelated issue. Try asking a new question with some more info.

Comment: This is weird. It works but it's weird. My DialogFragments were working with the support version of AlertDialog for weeks and then an unrelated change in code triggered a crash without error log in DialogFragment everytime I tried to use them. Anyway, thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you would read the logcat you would see this line too:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
```

So the fix is self-explaining: in the android manifest add this instead of your theme:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.AppCompat.NoTitleBar"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a AppCompat theme.

Instead of using `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"`

Make a custom theme in res/styles

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
// Here you can customize the theme
</style>
```

Then in your manifest change the theme to that custom theme `android:theme="@style/AppTheme"`